# Favicon doesn't display, but is being served up

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Have an SPA using React/Redux/Webpack with an Node webserver using Express. I'm using the `serve-favicon` package and when I hit `localhost:3000/favicon.ico`, the favicon is there. However it doesn't appear at the root.

My tag in my html is `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`.

I've tried clearing my cache, disabling my cache, getting rid of the leading `/` in my href, using `rel="shortcut icon"`, no luck.

Comment: Favicons tend to be cached very aggressively ... have you tried looking at it in a different browser or machine that has never hit localhost:3000 before and see if that works?

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded Firefox just to check and it's not there either. I also tried disabling use of cache using the chrome devtools, so it feels like that isn't the issue.